# How to get interface basetype via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

```
public interface IBar {} 
public interface IFoo : IBar {}

typeof(IFoo).BaseType == null
```

How can I get IBar?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
Type[] types = typeof(IFoo).GetInterfaces();
```

Edit: If you specifically want IBar, you can do:

```
Type type = typeof(IFoo).GetInterface("IBar");
```

Comment: What if `IBar` has a Generic Argument? And the argument is not known. `"IBar<>"` does not work.

Comment: @mxmissile Then you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx) and learn that  `interface IBar<T>`'s name (for the purpose of `GetInterface`) is `IBar\`1`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is that doesn't explain to me why ```GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetInterface(typeof(IPrefabForXmlInstantiater<>).Name) != null);``` works but ```GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPrefabForXmlInstantiater<>)));``` doen't ;/

Comment: @childno.de the reason is because Getinterfaces won't return the generic type definitions - you'll have to include them with

..GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsGenericType /*&& !x.IsGenericTypeDefinition*/).Select(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition())

Comment: Just want to add. You can use `nameof` to get the name of type  `Type type = typeof(IFoo).GetInterface(nameof(IBar));`

Answer (score 31):

An interface is not a base type. Interfaces are not part of the inheritance tree.

To get access to interfaces list you can use:

```
typeof(IFoo).GetInterfaces()
```

or if you know the interface name:

```
typeof(IFoo).GetInterface("IBar")
```

If you are only interested in knowing if a type is implicitly compatible with another type (which I suspect is what you are looking for), use type.IsAssignableFrom(fromType). This is equivalent of 'is' keyword but with runtime types.

Example:

```
if(foo is IBar) {
    // ...
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(typeof(IBar).IsAssignableFrom(foo.GetType())) {
    // ...
}
```

But in your case, you are probably more interested in:

```
if(typeof(IBar).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo))) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the other posters wrote, you can get the first interface from the GetInterface() list (if the list is not empty) to get the direct parent of IFoo. This would be the exact equivalent of your .BaseType attempt.