# Class Hierarchy for Interfaces C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, class, interface

I'm playing around with some classes and interfaces, and have developed a simple method to determine the hierarchy of a class, i.e. to identify the chain of inheritance.

```
public static void OutputClassHierarchy(Type ty)
{
    if (ty.BaseType == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Base", ty);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", ty, ty.BaseType);
    OutputClasshierarchy(ty.BaseType);
}
```

So, for

```
OutputClassHierarchy(typeof(System.Exception));
```

I get the output:

> System.Exception : System.Object
>
> System.Object : Base

Which is what I expect.

But, If I attempt the same with an Interface that implements another interface, i.e.

```
interface IMyInterface : IDisposable
{
    void Hello();
}

...

OutputClassHierarchy(typeof(IMyInterface));
```

I get the output:

> MyNameSpace.IMyInterface : Base

So, what is going on here? Is it possible to infer the interface hierarchy as declared above, or is there no such thing when it comes to interfaces?

Also, where is `System.Object` in all of this? I thought everything was built upon it.

Comment: Just FYI, you've consistently misspelled "hierarchy" throughout. Remember the rule is "I before E except when it's the other way".

Comment: There you get Eric. All fixed. I feel obliged to point out bad spelling too. The only thing that annoys, me more; is incorrect, punctuation...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are not derived from Object, so it won't show up when you output the base of it.  Here is Eric Lippert's comment on things which derive from Object (and things which are convertable to type Object).

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx

This SO answer may help answer your question about interfaces containing other interfaces:

[How to get interface basetype via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538541/how-to-get-interface-basetype-via-reflection)

Interfaces contain other interfaces, they don't derive from them so it won't show up when looking for it's base type.

Answer (score 4):

An interface doesn't have a *single* base type, as it could implement several other interfaces, e.g.

```
public IMyInterface : IDisposable, IComponent
```

However, you can get at those interfaces by using the `GetInterfaces` method:

```
var interfaces = typeof(IMyInterface).GetInterfaces();
```