# Why is my interface's BaseType null?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Interface definition

```
public interface IPayeePayrollRunInitialPayElementData : IPayeePayrollRunPayElementData
```

But in my code the BaseType of my interface is null. I cannot make any sense of this!

[image: Breakpoint and watches]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538541/how-to-get-interface-basetype-via-reflection

Comment: Was about to post the same link ^^

Comment: Interface **implementation** and base class **inheritance** are two different things. The `is` and similar type-cast operations will check for inheritance and implementation, but the type system reflects the true complexity present.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's [defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) to be so?

> Interfaces inherit from zero or more base interfaces; therefore, this property returns **null** if the **Type** object represents an interface. The base interfaces can be determined with [GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) or [FindInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx).

Comment: Of course that makes perfect sense because an interface may descend from multiple other interfaces.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) page;

> **Interfaces inherit from zero or more base interfaces; therefore, this
>   property returns null if the Type object represents an interface**. The
>   base interfaces can be determined with [`GetInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) or
>   [`FindInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx).

```
public interface IPayeePayrollRunInitialPayElementData : IPayeePayrollRunPayElementData
{ }

public interface IPayeePayrollRunPayElementData
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (Type tinterface in typeof(IPayeePayrollRunInitialPayElementData).GetInterfaces())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tinterface.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be;

```
IPayeePayrollRunPayElementData
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/lro7sA).

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces aren't derived from object.

Comment: Technically true, but this doesn't really answer the question. The question doesn't ask why `BaseType` isn't `object`, the question asks why `BaseType` isn't the interface that is effectively derived from.