# How can I get an interface from a class?

Tags: c#, class, types, interface

```
Type objType = displayed.GetType ();
displayable = (IDisplayable)objType.GetInterface ("IDisplayable");
```

The code above is giving me an error "Cannot cast from source to destination".
I would like to get a class' interface and store it in a variable.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538541/how-to-get-interface-basetype-via-reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Type.GetInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Type`, not an object.

To get an interface instance from an object, just cast the object.

```
displayable = (IDisplayable)displayed;
```

If that still gives you the same error, double-check that the type of `displayed` does, indeed, implement the interface `IDisplayable`.